# What are a set of example of tasks or problems where the Kolmogorov Complexity is Known -- ideally numerical values can be obtained?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, machine-learning, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

Is there a machine learning task (or any task/problem) that one can by construction know the Kolmogorov Complexity (or minimum description length)? I know the Kolmogorov Complexity is uncomputable but I was curious if there existed a set of tasks that the Kolmogorov Complexity can be known apriori and one can vary the Kolmogorov Complexity of those related tasks. I know Kolmogorov Complexity is uncomputable but I thought perhaps if it was by construction known then the task described -- perhaps it was doable.

Some ideas I thought of:

1. Random bitstrings: As mentioned before, the Kolmogorov complexity of a fair coin flip bitstring of length n is exactly n. No shorter description is possible.
2. Lookup tables: If you construct a lookup table that maps n-bit input binary strings to arbitrary outputs, the table requires 2^n entries, each of b bits. So the total complexity is 2^n * b.
3. Parity functions: As you mentioned, an n-bit parity function requires describing each of the n input bits, so the complexity is n. More formally, you need n + c bits where c is the size of the program that computes XOR. For large n, c is negligible.
4. Decision tree models: If you construct a full binary decision tree of depth d, it has 2^d leaves. To specify it requires 2^d output class labels + internal node conditions. Each condition can be specified in c bits. So total complexity is roughly c2^d.

Ideally I want to implement it in a computer to create this family of known Kolmogorov Complexity problems.

fyi: uncomputable means that there is no algorithm to compute it in general and I know KC is uncomputable in the general case.

Comment: The Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable but _"... von oben rekursiv aufzählbar."_ -- This hint found in German Wikipedia is missing in the French and Enghlish version. So, good luck. BTW, what the _hell_ will you do with this information? What does it help in real world?

Comment: @m-stgt uncomputable means that there is no algorithm to compute it in general. But it's easy to compute it for say a totally uniform random string of size n. It's n. specifying the string. 

I'd like to correlate it with computable measures of complexity of tasks.

Comment: @m-stgt fields like formal methods deal with uncomputable problems all the time. They reason by specific case usually and they have drawbacks. I'm not looking for a general algorithm :)

Comment: "know the Kolmogorov Complexity" of what?  I'm a bit lost by what you're asking, what string you want to know the KC of, and how that is supposed to be related to a ML problem.  What do you mean by the KC of a "task"?  Can you [edit] your post to formulate the problem statement more clearly/explicitly?

Comment: "the Kolmogorov complexity of a fair coin flip bitstring of length n is exactly n" - This is not correct.  The KC of a string depends on the string, not on how it was chosen.  The KC of a string chosen by flipping a fair coin n times is no greater than n, but it could be smaller.  For instance, TTTTTT..TTT is a possible outcome, and its KC is a constant.  There seem to be some misconceptions in the question about KC.

Answer (score 0):

**Not really.**

To establish the Kolmogorov complexity of a string, we'd have to know the halting status and output of all Turing machines with a shorter representation. Thus we can't have exact Kolmogorov complexities for anything with length longer than that for which we have a value for the busy beaver function. That's not a lot.

As [m-stgt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855866/what-are-a-set-of-example-of-tasks-or-problems-where-the-kolmogorov-complexity-i#comment10349245_4855866) found, the complexity is "recursively enumerable from above," which is to say there is a recursively enumerable decreasing sequence of functions that approaches the complexity function $K(s)$. The method, due to Kolmogorov, is however not enlightening and terminates on no inputs: Let the sequence $K_t(s)$ be indexed by natural $t$, and let $K_0(s)$ be a naïve upper bound on the complexity of $s$. Then, to find $K_{t+1}(s)$, run all Turing machines with descriptions shorter than $K_t$ for $t$ steps, and take $K_{t+1}(s)$ to be the minimum of $K_t(s)$ and the description lengths of any Turing machine that outputs $s$. This is obviously decreasing in $t$, and as $t\rightarrow\infty$ you have $K_t(s)\rightarrow K(s)$. This computes the complexity in the same sense that running all Turing machines of a certain length increasingly longer computes the busy beaver function: eventually you'll have the answer, but the tricky bit is knowing when you have it.

All of the examples you give are formulations of asking what the *maximum* complexity of a string of a given length is, and this will always be at least the length: you can't possibly describe all strings with descriptions of shorter lengths, as there are more strings of a given length than descriptions shorter. Meanwhile, there is a trivial upper bound on this given by the length of the program that hardcodes an output of a given length, which will be some negligible constant overhead on the string length.